# How to show a customized windows authentication with sql server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server-2008

i have a table in that i listdown the Ips to allow the access of service. my service is

website/service.asmx

in that there are hundreds of web methods.

```
the Table name: IPTable 
Column: IP nvarchar(max)
    202.192.25.150
    215.215.215.215
    115.119.185.199
```

when any person hit on above service then first it check the requester ip address  ,suppose if its in that list then open windows authentication popup (customize)*, else it will  redirect on root website root.
*Customize: by windows authentication I mean user/password will check from sql server's table H_user not actually windows users,

So my question is only that is this possible to show a customized windows authentication  ?

Comment: How can u do that ? A webservice doesn't have any interface.

Comment: What if service is called from Linux or MAC machine? Why you want to show that. That thing consumer of the service will manage. You just need to focus on authentication. Return fault or exception saying Invalid User.

Comment: Yes Mairaj you are right , but that's company requirement to hide the web methods which is currently open to see how many webmethods are in this service., second as for authentication if we go with windows authentication then issue is when we migrate from one server to another then we have to create windows users too, but if we go with customize authentication (sql server backend) then its easy to handle.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how we can implement the Windows authentication for this requirement.
But we can implement the customized authentication as below.

- Create an authentication method

  - Use `Request.UserHostAddress` to retrieve the client IP Address
  - Check that requested IP address is valid or not (from your table)
  - If valid returns true else false
- Call this authentication method in every web method
- If returns true proceed next; else redirect to root site

Authentication method signature:

```
public bool isAuthenticatedUser()
{
   -- get requested ip address
   -- check that requested ip address is available or not
   -- if requested ip address is available in DB then allow to proceed; else redirect to root site
}
```

Call the method in main.

Comment: Can you please share me some reference link of customized authentication with backend of sql server which looks like windows authentication popup.

Comment: Why you need to show the authentication popup window to user? in that case What the credentials user will enter it? my suggestion is implement the authentication as background process.